# What does @ do when it's already inside code (in contrast to inside markup)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm reading in Steven Sanderson's book about ASP.NET and I've reached a point where I'm really confused.

**Works**

```
@foreach (var link in Model)
{
    @Html.RouteLink(link, new { controller = "Product", action = "List", category = link, page = 1 });
}
```

**Doesn't work**

```
@foreach (var link in Model)
{
    Html.RouteLink(link, new { controller = "Product", action = "List", category = link, page = 1 });
}
```

*(Difference is the first character inside the block)*

In both scenarios Razor gets that it's code and not markup (HTML), so why did I have to put the `@` symbol at the beginning? What's the difference & what am I missing?

Edit:

I should clarify what doesn't work. It's a menu and `link` is the current category. Now, with `@` it works fine and you can see the links to the categories, but without it, it's as if there are no categories.. you don't see anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `foreach` the parser automagically works out if it is in code mode or razor template mode, allowing you to output html, razor or code.

The difference between the two statements is one is in razor template mode (working) and the other is in code mode (not working)

`Html.RouteLink` returns an `MvcHtmlString`, in your second example (in code mode) you execute a function and do nothing with that `MvcHtmlString` that is returned, so nothing is rendered when you request the page.

In the working first example, it's in razor template mode, when you do `@Html.RouteLink` it is added to the razor template, and razor interprets that correctly and renders your link for you.

Comment: In the interest of perusing this subject further, do you have any authoritative articles/white papers describing this behaviour? I'm woefully late to the Razor view engine party. =D

Comment: I've not seen anything, I only know from experience, it just makes sense when you think about what is happening.

Comment: Oh, it definitely makes sense. It's like executing a method with a return type and not assigning/outputting the value to anything. I was just curious about any further details. Thanks anyway. =)

Answer (score 2):

When you use the semicolon ; (or without the @)  it's executing a line of code but the return is not written to the response stream, whereas without it and by using the @ it is returning a result (MvcHtmlString) directly to the response stream at that point.

Comment: My source is from Mr. Sanderson's MVC 2 book on page 402 - Rendering a Partial Directly to the Response Stream.  In it, he explains why there is both a "RenderPartial" which requires a ; and a "Partial" Html helper function which does not require it.

Answer (score 2):

The `@` in this instance indicates that you want to output the result of the statement to the user. Similar to `Response.Write()`.

When the `@` sign is omitted, the function returns the result, but as it is not assigned or sent anywhere, it is lost.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember is that you can have html inside that foreach block as well:

Works:

```
@if (someConditionalExpression)
{
    <p>Only shown if the conditional was true.</p>
}
```

Since markup is also legal here, you need to use the `@` symbol to indicate to the view engine that you want code again, rather than markup. Otherwise, it's ambiguous which you wanted.

Comment: That's true but Razor knew that both are code and not markup. VS marked it as code (gray background), and also I tried to start the line with `@:` and then I **did** see it as if it was markup.